# R: Matching sample label order to hierarchically clustered order

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have data called `cleaned_mayo` that looks like:

```
                        Source         Tissue RIN Diagnosis Gender  AgeAtDeath ApoE   FLOWCELL PMI N_unmapped N_multimapping N_noFeature N_ambiguous ENSG00000223972
1924_TCX MayoBrainBank_Dickson TemporalCortex 5.6   Control      F 90_or_above   33 AC5R6PACXX   2    2773880        9656114     8225967     2876479               1
1926_TCX MayoBrainBank_Dickson TemporalCortex 7.8   Control      F          88   33 AC44HKACXX   2    2279283       12410116     9503353     3600252               2
1935_TCX MayoBrainBank_Dickson TemporalCortex 8.6   Control      F          88   33 AC5T2GACXX   3    3120169        8650081     9640468     4603751               0
1925_TCX MayoBrainBank_Dickson TemporalCortex 6.6   Control      F          89   33 BC6178ACXX   4    2046886       10627577     7533671     3361385               1
1963_TCX MayoBrainBank_Dickson TemporalCortex 9.7   Control      M 90_or_above   33 AC5T1WACXX   4    1810116        9611375     5343437     2983079               2
         ENSG00000227232 ENSG00000278267 ENSG00000243485 ENSG00000274890 ENSG00000237613 ENSG00000268020 ENSG00000240361 ENSG00000186092 ENSG00000238009 ENSG00000239945
1924_TCX              80               7               1               0               0               0               0               0               3               0
1926_TCX             113              22               9               0               0               0               0               0               0               0
1935_TCX             181              21               2               0               0               0               0               0               0               0
1925_TCX              75               9               5               0               0               0               0               0               2               0
1963_TCX              73              14               1               0               0               0               0               0               3               0
         ENSG00000233750
1924_TCX              18
1926_TCX               2
1935_TCX               8
1925_TCX              20
1963_TCX              13
```

I hierarchically cluster the expression columns of this data using the following code:

```
# Create the dendrogram for visualization
dend_expr<- cleaned_mayo[,14:60738] %>% # Isolate expression data
                  scale %>% # Normalize
                  dist  %>% # Compute distance measure
                  hclust %>% # Cluster hierarchically
                  as.dendrogram %>% # Convert to dendrogram type
                  assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(value= cleaned_mayo$Diagnosis, edgePar= "col") %>% # Color branches by diagnosis
                  as.ggdend()
```

I then visualize this dendrogram using:

```
# Plot dendrogram
ggplot(dend_expr, horiz= T, theme= NULL, labels= F) +
  ggtitle("Mayo Cohort: Hierarchical Clustering of Patients Colored by Diagnosis")
```

My problem is that using this `assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar` branch coloring technique, the order of my diagnoses no longer matches the clustered expression data. Thus my branches are colored according to the diagnosis order, which is not correct for the now permuted samples.

How can I match the order of these dataframes after clustering or otherwise correctly label the branches?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this issue myself and will post it here in case it helps anyone in the future.

Starting with creating the dendrogram:

```
# Create the dendrogram for visualization
dend_expr<- cleaned_mayo[,15:60739] %>% # Isolate expression data
                  scale %>% # Normalize
                  dist  %>% # Compute distance measure
                  hclust %>% # Cluster hierarchically
                  as.dendrogram()
```

I can then arrange my original data in the same order as the new hierarchically clustered data:

```
# Arrange labels in order with tree
tree_labels<- cleaned_mayo[order.dendrogram(dend_expr),]
```

I can then color the branches of the dendrogram using this order:

```
# Color branches by diagnosis
dend_expr<- assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(dend_expr, value= tree_labels$Diagnosis, edgePar= "col") %>%
            as.ggdend()
```

And then visualize the result:

```
# Plot dendrogram
ggplot(dend_expr, horiz= T, theme= NULL, labels= F) +
  ggtitle("Mayo Cohort: Hierarchical Clustering of Patients Colored by Diagnosis")
```